# Divide and sum in SQL

Tags: sql

I got this code and in this code I do a sum of the slow and fast driver. My Problem is I must divide this sum with the normal driver. I don´t know how I can do a division in this statement:

```
Select *
    FROM (

            Select date as Datetime, tevent.name as Event, level = case                                                                  
                           when levelname = 'High' then 'High'
                           when levelname = 'Normal'  then 'Normal'
                           when shiftname = 'Low'  then 'Low'
                           end, SUM(value) as sum

    from tCount inner join tEvent ON tCount.eventid = tevent.id
             where Name in ('Drive  Fast', 'Drive Slow')
               and date > getdate() -1
               and tevent.Name in ('E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08')
           and CalName = 'Drive'

             group by tevent.name, date, levelname
         ) as s

    PIVOT
    (
        SUM(sum)
        FOR Event IN (E01,E02,E03,E04,E05,E06,E07,E08)
    ) as p
    order by Datetime, level
```

And Then I put the same Select statement with the normal driver :

```
      ...  from tCount inner join tEvent ON tCount.eventid = tevent.id
                 where Name in ('drive normal') ...
```

And I would like to make a division like this:

```
(Sum('drive fast' + 'drive slow')/Sum('drive normal')) * 100
```

Comment: You may have to do that in two steps.  Meaning, get your sums, then use that result set as a derived table to do your division.  I don't think you can do them at the same time.

Comment: Tag your database with the database you are using.  Also sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff..i guess it should be sql server..looking at the `pivot` syntax and `getdate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simpler way to include different cases in different sums inside a SQL statement: sum a case, like in the below calculation of percent:

```
 Select ...
     , SUM(case Name 
            when 'drive fast' then Value 
            when 'drive slow' then value
            else 0 end) 
     / SUM(case Name 
            when 'drive normal' then value
            else 0 end) * 100 as percentage
 from ...
 where ...
 group by ...;
```

As I lack data to test this code, I created a query on the CARS table SAS delivers as training material, implementing the same principle.

```
select Cylinders
     , sum(case origin when 'USA' then EngineSize 
                       when 'Asia' then EngineSize 
                       else 0.0 end)
     / sum(case origin when 'Europe' then EngineSize 
                       else 0.0 end) 
     * 100 as percentage
from   sasHelp.cars
where  Cylinders in (4, 5, 6, 12)
group by Cylinders
```

Comment: Hi Dirk, in this statement SUM(case Name 
                when 'drive fast' then Value 
                when 'drive slow' then value
                else 0) 
         / SUM(case Name 
                when 'drive normal' then value
                else 0) * 100 as percentage                                                       it shows an error, in the near of the clamp,

Comment: You are right: I forgot to close my cases with an `end`. That is corrected now

Comment: Take care: you have upper and lower case words in your conditions, as well as a double blank. You might have to correct that before it works.

Comment: it does not work unfortunately, I changed the case words too

Comment: Sure it doesn't work - where condition excludes 'drive normal' values and you'll get 'division by zero' type error.

Comment: Richt, Arvo. Removed it.

Comment: As you did not supply test data, I can only test similar code on other data. You will have to apply the pattern in your situation yourself.

Comment: ok, another question, how can I make a sum of this expression: ....tevent.Name in ('E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08')

Comment: That can stay in the where clause (at least if I understand your question well)