# divide two table value in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I´ve got two tables in my Report:

[image]

I would like to divide the value from Scrap with the value from Table Total

--> (16227 / 425841) * 100

This is the code:

```
Select date as Datetime, tevent.name as Event, SUM(value) as sum

    from tCount inner join tEvent ON tCount.eventid = tevent.id
             where Name in ('Drive  Fast', 'Drive Slow')
               and date > getdate() -1
               and tevent.Name in ('E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08')
           and CalName = 'Drive'
```

The sum of these: 'E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08', I did it in the report like this: Sum(Fields!E01.Value+Fields!E02.Value+Fields!E03.Value+...

And for the other table it looks like this:

```
Select date as Datetime, tevent.name as Event, SUM(value) as sum

        from tCount inner join tEvent ON tCount.eventid = tevent.id
                 where Name in ('Drive Normal')
                   and date > getdate() -1
                   and tevent.Name in ('E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08')
               and CalName = 'Drive'
```

And I must do a division of this two statements.
But if I put in the Scrap Expression the value from Total then the result is wrong. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Are these two tables from two different datasets?  How do the two tables relate to each other - is there a key not shown in your example above?

Comment: yes the two tables are from two different datasets, The Value of this both table is in one table in the database, the name is different. I tried to do it in one statement but it would not work. here is my other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158424/divide-and-sum-in-sql/34158787?noredirect=1#comment56065155_34158787)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data your datasets are returning.  It is very difficult to understand the structure you are reporting on from your description

Comment: OK, so I assume the dates match between the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your question, you have two datasets, and you want to calculate the percentage of Scrap of the Total

To replicate your problem I have created two DataSets as follows

```
Scrap Dataset
myDateTime  Event  mySum
01/01/2015  Scrap  16227 
02/01/2015  Scrap  14637 
03/01/2015  Scrap  14174

Total Dataset
myDateTime  Event  mySum
01/01/2015  Total  425841 
02/01/2015  Total  434024 
03/01/2015  Total  405216
```

Create a Table in your report and set column 1 to be `mySum` from `ScrapDataSet`

Then you can use the [LOOKUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee210531.aspx) function in Column 2 to look up a specific value from another dataset assuming there is a common field.  In this instance

```
=Lookup(Fields!myDateTime.Value, 
        Fields!myDateTime.Value, 
        Fields!mySum.Value, 
        "TotalDataSet")
```

Compares `myDateTime` in `ScrapDataSet` to `myDateTime` in `TotalDataSet`, and where there is a match returns `mySum` from `TotalDataSet`

You can then combine these two expressions as follows to get the percentage as required in Column 3

```
=Fields!mySum.Value / 
 (Lookup(Fields!myDateTime.Value, 
         Fields!myDateTime.Value, 
         Fields!mySum.Value, 
         "TotalDataSet"))
```

In this example I formatted this third column to be a percentage format to 2 decimal places.

These steps result in a table that looks like this

[image]

Hopefully this is the output you require.  If you need further assistance please ask with clarification of the original question.

*As a final note Sum and DateTime are not recommended field names as these are both keywords that can be used in SSRS to either define a type of perform a function.  These should really be renamed – as I have done in the example above.*

Comment: I have one question, do you know how I can make a sum of these events: ...and tevent.Name in ('E01','E02','E03','E04','E05','E06','E07','E08')... in a sql statement

Comment: Not without more information on what your actual table structure looks like and I can't tell that from either this question or the other one you linked to previously.